# Find the sum of the following series using

Tags: sequences-and-series

> The sum of series $\frac{601}{50}(\frac{1}{1+1^2+1^4} + \frac{2}{1+2^2+2^4} + \frac{3}{1+3^2+3^4} +....+\frac{24}{1+24^2+24^4})$ is

Comment: a rational number. In fact, $6$. I used...

Comment: i am uanble to find the answer, any method will suffice as long as it is solved.

Comment: please can you give me full solutions i still can't figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

Consider $$S_n=\sum_{i=1}^n \frac i{1+i^2+i^4}=\frac 12\left(\sum_{i=1}^n \frac 1{1-i+i^2}-\sum_{i=1}^n \frac 1{1+i+i^2}\right)$$ which beautifully telescopes.

Answer (score 0):

Set $$\color{blue}{a_k=  \frac{1}{k^2 -k +1} \implies a_{k+1}=  \frac{1}{(k+1)^2 -k } =\frac{1}{k^2+ k +1}} $$

But since $ (k^2 -k +1)(k^2 +k +1) =k^4 +k^2 +1$ we have,

$$ a_{k+1} -a_k = \frac{1}{k^2 +k +1}-  \frac{1}{k^2 -k +1} = \frac{2k}{(k^2 -k +1)(k^2 +k +1)} =\frac{2k}{k^4 +k^2 +1}$$

Then

$$a_n-a_0 = \sum_{k=0}^{n-1}a_{k+1} -a_k=2\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac{k}{k^4 +k^2 +1} $$

Therefore,

$$\frac{1}{1+1^2+1^4} + \frac{2}{1+2^2+2^4} + \frac{3}{1+3^2+3^4} +....+\frac{24}{1+24^2+24^4} =\frac{1}{2}(a_{25}-a_0) \\= \color{blue}{\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{1}{25^2 -25+1}-1\right)}$$